# Suddenly project files can not find jdk in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, manifest

My project was working fine till last night . Today when i open stdio then suddenly errors had come saying that LayoutInflator not found , Activity class not found and every class which we always see on import is not working .When i am trying to run app then it is opening "edit configuration" window . I had set up jdk and stdio sdk path also and declared activity in manifest with all configuration but i lost everytime . I am attaching my manifest and build files .
manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shubham.sharma.bunktrackingapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="TeacherPanel.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CoordinatorPanel.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my gradle code is here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shubham.sharma.bunktrackingapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0-beta1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')


}
```

Comment: Perhaps your jdk and sdk directory has been damaged (may be deleted or don't have permission to the directory). If nothing happens like that then copy your full project into a safe place. Then give a full uninstall to Android studio including deleting the sdk directory also. And then install it again. It is the best solution to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jdk is issue then ff Ubuntu - do - > sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -here first check what version of java you have  if its is windows setup your jdk/jre in environment variables to java 8  For these two steps you will get lot of links from google.if still it is not resolved last option then try redo the last step due to which this error has occurred.Try creating another android project and see your getting same errors in java file, if no then its not jdk issue this is something has to do with you project R file as there is some error in your xml files. Try to clean/re-build project.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problem with the build configuration just go to Option Build and choose rebuild project.If it doesn't works then let me know what are the errors that you see.

Comment: This is not a proper answer of the question. You should have added this as a comment.